# problem with cl_image_tag on Rails with Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I've got a strange situation. Which is why I end up posting on Stackoverflow...

Basically, I've got a Ruby on Rails 6.1 app, running in production, on which I recently implemented Cloudinary (replacing Amazon S3). Cloudinary allows to get optimised pictures with custom sizes and format, so it's pretty amazing to use.

But I've got a problem with the `cl_image_tag`.

**When running my code in local environment :**

Putting this in *development.rb* :

```rb
  config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Causes this tag to fail to get the picture. Becauses it misses the main folder in which the image is stored (*my_app/*)

```html
<%= cl_image_tag("homepage/banner.webp", quality: 'auto', width: 1932, height: 904) %>
```

So I have to write this instead if I want it to work :

```html
<%= cl_image_tag("my_app/homepage/banner.webp", quality: 'auto', width: 1932, height: 904) %>
```

**BUT if I do that, then my production environment will fail because it uses :**

*development.rb :*

```rb
  config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

*index.html.erb :*

```rb
<%= cl_image_tag("homepage/banner.webp", quality: 'auto', width: 1932, height: 904) %>
```

*.env :*

```
MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME_IN_CLOUDINARY=my_app
```

So I find myself stuck between one config working only in local, and one working only in production. What the heck ?! What am I missing ? I can't find anything on StackOverflow or Cloudinary's documentation.

Edit:
My first guess is that the `MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME_IN_CLOUDINARY`env variable is only loaded in the code if this line appears :

```rb
  config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

But I can't use that in my local environment because I don't want my local images to be uploaded and take space on my cloudinary storage. So I have to find a workaround...

Thanks in advance for any help people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudinary SDK was designed for the delivery of assets from your Cloudinary account and not from a local environment, therefore the `cl_image_tag` helper method isn't configured to check the full path of your local application when generating the URL but simply creates it based on the path string provided as the first parameter and the optional transformation parameters.

Cloudinary has the option to create sub-accounts under the same parent account when on the Advanced plan and higher, so you can have one cloud for your dev environment and one for your production. Each will have its own API credentials which you can add as environmental variables based on the environment it runs on.

If you are on a plan that is lower than the Advanced one, you can create two separate accounts with two different email addresses so one will be used for dev and the other for production (those two will not share the same quotas. Each will have its own). Code-wise, it will look the same as having the two clouds under the same parent account. You will still be provided with different API credentials for each cloud. The only difference will be when you log into your account, you won't be able to seamlessly change between the different sub-accounts but you will need to log out and log in to the other account if and when needed.

You can also just continue using your suggested workaround if you prefer to take this path. It's perfectly fine as it does not require you to fork the repository and detach it from future updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloudinary in development, too, to basically have the same setting as in production, so that it will grab the image from cloudinary instead of your local machine.

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

Comment: Yeah sure, but If I do that then Cloudinary will be used to upload my local images to cloudinary, and this will take some storage in my cloudinary space... and I don't want that. What I want is to be able to use my cloudinary images used for my static Frontend, but to keep storing the uploaded images in local.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a "workaround" to fix this, even if I'm sure this isn't the ideal solution and that I shouldn't be having this problem. So until someone offers me a better solution, here is mine:

*application_helper.rb* :

```rb
Rails.env == 'production' ? '' : "#{ENV['MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME_IN_CLOUDINARY']}/"
```

*application_helper.html.erb* :

```html
<%= cl_image_tag("#{cloudinary_folder}homepage/banner.webp", quality: 'auto', width: 1932, height: 904) %>
```

Using this helper allows me to set cloudinary_folder to "" in production, and "my_app/" in development environement.

NB: If you think I could just use the ENV variable.M.. no I can't. Because when in production, Cloudinary's cl_image_tag uses the same ENV variable to set the folder in which it needs to store the uploaded images, and get the static images.